# Default Adam optimizer doesn't work in tf.keras but string `adam` does

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've been trying out TensroFlow v2 beta and I'm trying out the tf.keras models.

When I compile a model and select the optimizer to be the string `'adam'`. The model can be trained properly:

```py
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(x, y)
```

But when I try to use the default optimizer `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()` it can't be trained and outputs a `nan` loss at each iteration.

```py
adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(x, y)
```

Isn't the string `'adam'` supposed to be the default adam optimizer or am I missing something? I've tried several hyperparameters (`learning_rate`, `beta_1`, `beta_2`, etc.), but none seem to work. This is a big deal because I might not want to use the default hyperparameters all the time.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit of digging it seems that when you type the string `'adam'` it calls another adam, which it refers to as [adam_v2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizers.py#L800).

This can be found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py#L31).

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam

adam = Adam()

model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit(x, y)
```

Comment: Typo: "tenforflow" should be "tensorflow"

Comment: @QuinnCulver Nice catch, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From what I can gather there are now 2 different implementations of the optimizers. Using optimizer='adam' seems to use this implementation:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/adam.py

You can import explicitly as:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizer_v2 import adam as adam_v2
```